# Brass piece won't unscrew

Tags: plumbing, bathroom-fixtures

The following picture shows a filter module on my shower mixing valve. The piece won't unscrew and the 10mm Allen socket is stripped. I tried heating the piece with a heating gun but it didn't make any difference.

At this point, what our my options for removing this piece?

[image]

Comment: Brass is soft. _Before_ you stripped the bolt head, you needed some sort of penetrating oil (WE-40™, PB Blaster™, or the like) to try to get into the threads to loosen any gunk built up and lubricate. Now, probably your best bet is [crip659's mechanical methods](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/267087/34147) or a full on replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Choices for that problem are to force a bigger(11mm) allen wrench/allen socket tip in, maybe with the help of a hammer.

If possible cut a slot in the top for a flat bladed screwdriver.

After watching the video, might be able to drill two holes on the sides of the head and use two rods/needle nose pliers to turn the head.

Use a drill and drill out the screw/bolt.

Not quite sure but soldering/silver soldering/blazing a nut on top might work.

Will depend on how tight that screw/bolt is in the threads.

Comment: Video? I missed a video??

Comment: @FreeMan  Was in the question OP asked earlier on removing the other filter.

Comment: @crip659 The crew is extremely tight - before I stripped the socket, I could put my entire weight of 225lb on the 10" long allen key.

Comment: Might just have to go with drilling out that screw if that tight.  That is almost enough to put a curve in the key.

Comment: @crip659  Is  there nothing along the lines of using heat, chemicals or tapping it with a hammer, etc?

Comment: Penetrating oil plus tapping with a hammer might help, but you do not have a good turning connection point any more.  Check with the filter that does come out and see if there is enough metal to drill two holes to place steel rods/allen keys and to use a wrench/piece of metal to turn.